# SKU update on WooCommerce product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, sku

I need to update the SKU of a WooCommerce product but nothing I tried works.

I'm trying to update the SKU of a product. I build a new select custom field (´´id=>'_leadlovers_integration_product'´´ on the code below) on the inventory settings with options I import by API from another plataform). This works fine. I can save the code, print it. But I can´t simply make the update of the SKU with this code.

I've tried a lot of snipets but nothing works...

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_leadlovers_custom_fields');
function save_leadlovers_custom_fields( $post_id )
{
    //These two guys works perfectly
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_leadlovers_integration_check', esc_attr( $_POST['_leadlovers_integration_check'] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_leadlovers_integration_product', esc_attr( $_POST['_leadlovers_integration_product'] ) );
    
    //First, I tried this... no success
    //update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', esc_attr( $_POST['_leadlovers_integration_product'] ) );

    //Then I tried this, with no changes, forcing by hand the 
    //update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', '30445' );

    //I tried using the function set_sku() too... nothing happens
    //$product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    //$product->set_sku( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_leadlovers_integration_product', true ) );

    //nothing too with this...
        $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $product->set_sku( '30445' ) ;

        ///i tried even make the procedure on other function...

}
```

Well, someone have an idea what happens, or... not happens??

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`update_post_meta` should actually work fine. You should still use this last `save` function for the other set_sku function. In that:

```
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $product->set_sku( '30445' );
    $product->save();
```

If that doesn't work either, there's a problem with your `woocommerce_process_product_meta` hook or it's not working for the time you want it to.

EDIT

Or this I'm guessing. You might actually be using a hook too early to save meta. So you are saving something but again _sku is saved again right after your function. So you should try a different hook to make sure it works at the right time. It would be nice if you could provide more details so that I can assist you.

EDIT 2

I reviewed it again maybe the hook should work. Can you delay the runtime by trying this?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_leadlovers_custom_fields', 50);
```

Comment: Great man, this works: adding this line [$product->save();] AND  seting the priority to 50 on the hook. Booth are necessary! THANKS Man!

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_product_object_save', 'before_product_save', 10, 2);

function before_product_save($product, $datastore) {

    $product->set_sku('thesku');
}
```

This hook runs just before saving a product to the database. This hook specific for changing any product data just before saving.

Comment: Thanks, but i didn't try this because I prefer to test the other possibilities on the ``woocommerce_process_product_meta`` first and works there...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Akin and @mujuonly...

I tried first to set up the priority to 50 and using `$product->set_sku()` but, so, we need to use `$product->save` together... only to save didn't work.

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_leadlovers_custom_fields', 50);
function save_leadlovers_custom_fields( $post_id ){  
    $product = wc_get_product( $post_id );
    $product->set_sku( '12345' ) ;
    $product->save();
}
```

Them, I tried to use update_post_meta with priority seted to 50 and just works...

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_leadlovers_custom_fields', 50);
function save_leadlovers_custom_fields( $post_id )
{
    // now updating the sku with my select...
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sku', esc_attr( $_POST['_leadlovers_integration_product'] ) );
}
```

Thanks